# How to trigger login in my mvc form by pressing enter key?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a small login form in my login.cshtml, now submit button works fine but I need to make form work by pressing enter as well, should I use some jquery code or is possible to solve this without jquery?

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", id = "login_form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="margin-bottom-20">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "pull-left" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="hidden" />
                    <button type="button" id="btn-login" data-style="expand-right" class="btn btn-action btn-block ladda-button"><span class="ladda-label">Login</span></button>
                </div>
```

Comment: share... your... code...

Comment: Please share some of your existing code, the research you've done previously before asking this question, and what you imagine the end result *should* look like.

Comment: here's a part of my login.cshtml code, I've tried to do it with jquery

Comment: <script>
        $("body").keyup(function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                $("#btn_login").click();
            }
        });

    </script>

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Formbegin").keypress(function (e) {
        keycode = e.keyCode || e.charCode || e.which //for cross browser
        if (keycode == 13)    //keyCode for the Enter / Return key
        {
            var defaultbutton = $(this).attr("DefaultButton");
            $("#" + defaultbutton).click();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: where should I add my script tag?

Comment: If you're asking questions like that, I'd recommend you do some research on the basics of website creation. [Here's a useful website for you](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp)